# Update customer address using address id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-address, address

How can I update customer address by address id in Magento 2 programmatically  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know the address id (`$addressId`) you can use the address repository to load and save updated addresses:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $addressRepository;

/**
 * Sync constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
) {
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
}

public function changeAddress($addressId)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address */
    $address = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);
    $address->setCity('customCity'); // Update city
    $address->setCountryId('UK'); // Update country id 
    // update what ever you want
    $this->addressRepository->save($address);
}
```

Comment: @srg I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: How to check if address id exist or not?

Comment: getById is not working for me

Comment: @jafarpinjar it will work when you use a try-catch construction

Comment: no Siarhey, i have used it, its not working for me, here is the link for my issue
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240352/how-to-update-customer-address-using-custom-api-in-magento2

Comment: I am getting this error, Invalid value of \"1\" provided for the regionId field.

Comment: region and region id is not working

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau, This code is not working when I tried to update the data. After this save operation, I'm trying to get the city value, it returns the updated value only. But not reflecting in db and frontend.

Comment: @Ramya It will change only the customer address, not shipping or billing address in existing orders.

Comment: @jafarpinjar When you are changing the country_id field you must manually change the region_id from the list of corresponding values specific for that country.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau, If I want to update the shipping and billing address means, how do I proceed?. The customer address was saved at customer_address_entity table at the time of registartion. But that table data with id (29) and the shipping and billing address edit id also 29. So, I'm trying to update the same address only

Comment: What happens if $addressId does not exist? I get exception, but it does not mean.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Hi. In case address does not exist you must catch the `NoSuchEntityException` and create a new address entity from scratch (using the address factory). Then you can proceed using code from the answer. If you want to get more detailed answer, please write you own question with code you are using and give me a link. I will try to help you :)

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Thanks...!!! I got the non exists address id using the repository but it was directly through exception. Generally, If no record is found then the model/factory return null. So I just confirm with you.

Answer (score 3):

> If you want to Update address by addressID with region details
>
> Use below code

```
$adddress_id = 12;
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$address = $obj->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\Address')->load($adddress_id);
$address->setTelephone('7894561230')
        ->setCountryId('US')
        ->setPostcode('12345-6789)
        ->setCity('boston')
        ->setRegionId(57)
        ->setRegionCode('TX')
        ->setRegion('Texas')
        ->setStreet('102 san diago') //you can also pass array for street
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1')
        ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
        ->save();
```

**NOTE: You should not use the ObjectManager directly!**