# region Id error on updating address using address Id in magneto2

Tags: magento2, address, regions

I followed below link to update address using address id

[Update customer address using address id in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188310/update-customer-address-using-address-id-in-magento-2/188316?noredirect=1#comment335721_188316)

I am getting this error upon executing this code

```
protected $addressRepository;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
 ) {
$this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
}

public function changeAddress($addressId)
{
  $AddressId = 381993;

if(isset($AddressId) && $AddressId !=''){
            try{
                $address = $this->addressRepository->getById($AddressId);
                $address->setFirstname('test');
                $address->setLastname('test');
                $address->setCountryId('GB');
                $address->setRegion()->setData(array('region' => 'test'));
                $address->setPostcode('t9 1rd');
                $address->setCity('test');
                $this->addressRepository->save($address);
             }catch(\Exception $e){
               print_r($e->getMessage());
             }

            }
   }
```

I am getting this error upon using this code

```
  "message": "Invalid value of \"1\" provided for the regionId field.",
```

I tried

```
   $address->setRegion(); also same error again
```

What is the mistake in above code? Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$countryId = 'US' //static set for example
$regionName = 'Alaska' //static set for example

/** @var \Magento\Directory\Model\Region $region */
$region = $this->regionFactory->create();
$region->loadByName($regionName, $countryId);
// load region on the 
// basis of state name and country id
$regionId = $region->getRegionId(); // obtain region_id

$address = $this->addressRepository->getById($AddressId);
$address->setFirstname('test');
$address->setLastname('test');
$address->setCountryId('US');
if (isset($regionId)) {
     $address->setRegionId($regionId);
}
$address->setPostcode('t9 1rd');
$address->setCity('Test City');
$this->addressRepository->save($address);
```

By default "**region**" is required if the selected "**country**" have dat for states or cities, else "**region**" is not needed.
(You have set an empty region **$address->setRegion()**)

Also, "**region_id**" is the primary key for the region should be the same as in database.

Try to run the above sample and check.

Comment: $address->setRegion()  i used, but its not working

Comment: What value did you put in region? It should exist in database.

Comment: my issue is similar to this one,
I need to update address from request
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240352/how-to-update-customer-address-using-custom-api-in-magento2

Comment: hi @Milind, This is not working for me

Comment: Hi @jafarpinjar I have updated the code obtain the region_id

Comment: hi @Milind, getting this error, Call to undefined method Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Address::addData()

Comment: Sorry Address repository return mistook as Address model.
I have again.

Comment: hi @Milind, not cleared with your comment, what change i need to do?

Comment: I have removed addData. Kindly check the code now.

Comment: yes i used this code to set regin, $address->setRegion(), i got below error, Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Address::setRegion()

Comment: `$address->setRegionId($regionId);`
I am setting region ID, not region. Kindly verify.

Comment: If our county is KWT then I need to set the state programmatically it showing me the error like setRegion() must implement interface Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface

Comment: Yes, as the `\Magento\Directory\Model\Region` does not implement the `RegionInterface`, why  not use the `$address->setRegionId($regionId);` ?